# Duda sobre funcionamiento de array_merge en PHP para obtener la posición de todas las vocales en un texto

Tags: php, array

practicando un poco con PHP7 me he puesto a escribir una función que obtenga las vocales de un texto, pero estoy un poco confuso ya que no me muestra nada en pantalla y no me da error por ningún lado, tiene que ser que la función ***array_merge*** no me esta añadiendo correctamente el array que le paso, al original.

**Lo que quiero hacer es retornar un array asociativo con la posición del String donde encontró la vocal con la respectiva vocal.**

Seguro que es un fallo de lógica pero yo no lo veo, aquí esta el código:

```
$texto = "Hoy es un dia excelente para programar, me siento listo para poner en practica mis conocimientos en PHP 7.";

   function countVowels($argument) {

    $length = count($argument);
    $vowels = array();
    $textToLower = strtolower($argument);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

       if ($textToLower[$i] === 'a' || $textToLower[$i] === 'e' || 
            $textToLower[$i] === 'i' || $textToLower  === 'o' || 
             $textToLower  === 'u') {

         $new_array = array($i => $textToLower[$i]);
         array_merge($vowels, $new_array);
       }
     }
     return $vowels;
    }

   $superVowels = countVowels($texto); //Recojo el array que retorna la función
    //Lo recorro para mostrarlo en pantalla
    foreach ($superVowels as $position => $vowel) {
     print "En la posicion: " . $position . " está la vocal: " . $vowel . "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: No te hace falta usar un array_merge. puedes hacer $vowels[$i] = $textToLower[$i];

Comment: Aparte en la comparacion con u y o te falta definier la posicion del array de letras [$i]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay algunos detalles que cambiaria de tu funcion

Cambiar `count` por `strlen`

No es necesario hacer el `array_merge`

Agregar a tu if

```
$textToLower[$i]  === 'o'
```

Y cambiar

```
$new_array = array($i => $textToLower[$i]);
```

Por esto :

```
$vowels[$i] = $textToLower[$i];
```

Y por ultimo

```
foreach ($superVowels as $position => $vowel) {
    print "En la posicion: " . $position . " está la vocal: " . $vowel . "<br>";
}
```

Puedes ver funcionando esto [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a40349c332a852759a7af596f6f3a56a5a821b90)

Comment: Hey muchas gracias por la respuesta, no me di cuenta de los '$i' que se me escaparon de las comprobaciones y tampoco conocía ese entorno de testeo para probar PHP. He aprendido mucho tanto escribiendo el código como con la respuesta :)

Comment: @RomeroBinary me alegro que te haya funcionado y que bhayas aprendido, todas las respuestas que te dieron son diferentes y buenas :D

Answer (score 1):

Si solo quieres filtrar las vocales puedes hacer algo de este estilo que queda limpio y te aprovechas de la potencia de las expresiones regulares :)

```
<?php
$texto = "Hoy es un dia excelente para programar, me siento listo para poner en practica mis conocimientos en PHP 7.";
print preg_replace('/[^aeiou]+/', '', $texto);
```

Y si quieres justo lo que dices, creo que esto te puede valer:

```
<?php

$texto = "Hoy es un dia excelente para programar, me siento listo para poner en practica mis conocimientos en PHP 7.";
$array = str_split($texto);

$newArray = array_filter($array, function($val) {
    return preg_match('/[aeiou]/i', $val) != 0;
});
```

¡Saludos! :)

Comment: Me gusta esta alternativa con regexp, muy elegante.

Comment: En vez de hacer un split y aplicar el regex sobre cada ítem, convendría usar `preg_match_all` con `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` para obtener la posición de cada vocal en una única pasada

Answer (score 1):

Veo mucho código para resolver este problema, aquí os dejo mi solución:

Creo creo que el código se explica por si solo:

```
<?php
$texto = "Hoy es un dia excelente para programar.";

preg_match_all("/[aeiouAEIOU]/", $texto, $encontradas, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
foreach($encontradas[0] as $v)
{
    $posicion_vs_vocal[$v[1]] = $v[0];
    print "En la posicion: " . $v[1] . " está la vocal: " . $v[0] . "<br>";
}

print_r($posicion_vs_vocal);
```

Resultado:

```
En la posicion: 1 está la vocal: o
En la posicion: 4 está la vocal: e
En la posicion: 7 está la vocal: u
En la posicion: 11 está la vocal: i
En la posicion: 12 está la vocal: a
En la posicion: 14 está la vocal: e
En la posicion: 17 está la vocal: e
En la posicion: 19 está la vocal: e
En la posicion: 22 está la vocal: e
En la posicion: 25 está la vocal: a
En la posicion: 27 está la vocal: a
En la posicion: 31 está la vocal: o
En la posicion: 34 está la vocal: a
En la posicion: 36 está la vocal: a


$posicion_vs_vocal
(
    [1] => o
    [4] => e
    [7] => u
    [11] => i
    [12] => a
    [14] => e
    [17] => e
    [19] => e
    [22] => e
    [25] => a
    [27] => a
    [31] => o
    [34] => a
    [36] => a
)
```

Comment: `/[aeiouAEIOU]/` se puede acortar como `/[aeiou]/i`.

Answer (score 0):

Asi quedaría tu código:
- Necesitas convertir tu texto en array para recorrerlo y leerlo, y ver la longitud de este array.
- El print lo puedes hacer al recorrerlo directamente, no es necesario almacenarlo en un array y recorrerlo después.

```
$texto = "Hoy es un dia excelente para programar, me siento listo para poner en practica mis conocimientos en PHP 7.";


   function countVowels($argument) {

    $length = count($argument);
    $vowels = array();
    $textToLower = strtolower($argument);
    $textToLower = str_split($textToLower);
    $length = count($textToLower);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

       if ($textToLower[$i] === 'a' || $textToLower[$i] === 'e' || 
            $textToLower[$i] === 'i' || $textToLower[$i]  === 'o' || 
             $textToLower[$i]  === 'u') {

         //$new_array = array($i => $textToLower[$i]);
         print "En la posicion: " . $i . " está la vocal: " . $textToLower[$i] . "<br>";
       }
     }
     return $vowels;
    }

   $superVowels = countVowels($texto);
```

Answer (score -1):

No te hace falta usar array_merge para ello, puedes asignar directamente el texto a la posicion dentro del array.

```
    $texto = "Hoy es un dia excelente para programar, me siento listo para poner en practica mis conocimientos en PHP 7.";

   function countVowels($argument) {

        $length = count($argument);
        $vowels = array();
        $textToLower = strtolower($argument);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

            if ($textToLower[$i] === 'a' || $textToLower[$i] === 'e' || 
                 $textToLower[$i] === 'i' || $textToLower[$i]  === 'o' || 
                 $textToLower[$i]  === 'u') {

                 $vowels [$i] = $textToLower[$i];
            }
         }
         return $vowels;
     }

   $superVowels = countVowels($texto); //Recojo el array que retorna la función
   //Lo recorro para mostrarlo en pantalla
   foreach ($superVowels as $position => $vowel) {
     print "En la posicion: " . $position . " está la vocal: " . $vowel .    "<br>";
   }
```